# PGF addplot3 not working for triangular region of table of x, y, z data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a file `example.dat` that stores x, y, z values. The dimensions of this file are 6000 rows (including the header row) and 3 columns. I am using pgf to generate a surface plot. The MWE is shown below. I keep getting the following error message:

`Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 'plot mesh' needs either '[mesh/rows=<N>]' or '[mesh/cols=<N>]' set, but it did not find any of them. I also tried rows = sqrt(num points) = sqrt(6045) = 77.74959`

After I add `mesh/rows=<N>` to match the number of rows in `example.dat`, I get another error message:

`Package pgfplots Error: the arguments of [mesh/rows=6047, mesh/cols=3] assume 18141 points, but I actually got N = 6045 points! The data appears to be incomplete or over complete`.

I suspect this error is since the data in `example.dat` samples a triangular region, with the first column being the x-values, second column being the y-values, and the third column being the z-values in that triangular region. I have included a small snippet of `example.dat` below.

How can I make the surface plot to work? See **MWE** and example.dat snippet below:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit, decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{example.dat}{\surface}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[
        mesh/rows=6047, 
        mesh/cols=3,
        view={45}{30},
        ]
    \addplot3[surf] table [x ={X}, y={Y}, z={Z}] {\surface};        

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**SNIPPIT OF example.dat FILE**

```
X   Y   Z
0.46608831586965926 0.11557597337182614 0.0000221656414657323
0.46608831586965926 0.11657597337182614 0.
0.46708831586965927 0.11487986777623747 0.00008847564624375748
0.46708831586965927 0.11587986777623747 0.
0.46708831586965927 0.11687986777623748 0.
0.46808831586965927 0.1141837621806488  0.0001986557070272621
0.46808831586965927 0.1151837621806488  0.
0.46808831586965927 0.1161837621806488  0.
0.46808831586965927 0.1171837621806488  0.
0.46908831586965927 0.11348765658506015 0.0003524394523312657
0.46908831586965927 0.11448765658506015 0.
0.46908831586965927 0.11548765658506015 0.
0.46908831586965927 0.11648765658506015 0.
0.46908831586965927 0.11748765658506015 0.
0.46908831586965927 0.11848765658506015 0.
0.47008831586965927 0.11279155098947148 0.0005495682535301971
0.47008831586965927 0.11379155098947148 0.
0.47008831586965927 0.11479155098947148 0.
0.47008831586965927 0.11579155098947148 0.
0.47008831586965927 0.11679155098947148 0.
0.47008831586965927 0.11779155098947149 0.
0.47008831586965927 0.11879155098947149 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11209544539388283 0.000789791040502974
0.47108831586965927 0.11309544539388283 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11409544539388283 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11509544539388283 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11609544539388283 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11709544539388284 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11809544539388284 0.
0.47108831586965927 0.11909544539388284 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11139933979829414 0.0010728641255012272
0.47208831586965927 0.11239933979829414 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11339933979829414 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11439933979829414 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11539933979829414 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11639933979829414 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11739933979829414 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11839933979829415 0.
0.47208831586965927 0.11939933979829415 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.11070323420270549 0.0013985510348768493
0.47308831586965927 0.11170323420270549 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.11270323420270549 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.11370323420270549 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.11470323420270549 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.1157032342027055  0.
0.47308831586965927 0.1167032342027055  0.
0.47308831586965927 0.1177032342027055  0.
0.47308831586965927 0.11870323420270548 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.11970323420270548 0.
0.47308831586965927 0.12070323420270548 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11000712860711681 0.001766622348345348
0.47408831586965927 0.11100712860711681 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11200712860711681 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11300712860711681 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11400712860711681 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11500712860711682 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11600712860711682 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11700712860711682 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11800712860711682 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.11900712860711682 0.
0.47408831586965927 0.1200071286071168  0.
0.47408831586965927 0.1210071286071168  0.
0.4750883158696593  0.10931102301152815 0.002176855545407197
0.4750883158696593  0.11031102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11131102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11231102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11331102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11431102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11531102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11631102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11731102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11831102301152815 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.11931102301152814 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.12031102301152814 0.
0.4750883158696593  0.12131102301152814 0.
0.4760883158696593  0.10861491741593947 0.002629034858747714
```

Comment: `rows` times `cols` gives the total number of points that PGFPlots expect. Imagine a grid that is stretched first to match the x-y coordinates and then raised to the z height. How would you interpret your data - forget what PGFPlots expect. -just explain what your data actually means!? Maybe it is not a surface at all? -just some needles(bars) sticking up where z is not zero.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, could you provide an answer that implements your suggestion? I have `rows` and `cols` in the MWE. The data is a surface since I have managed to plot it using alternative software, but I would now like to achieve the plot in PGFPlots. Please recall that I have only provided a small snippet of the data file for which the values of x and y mostly give zero values for z. The full data file will give a smooth surface, but the MWE provided will support the problem I currently face.

Comment: I can not answer, as I do not know how to interpret your data and I do also not know how to do it. Could you include a screenshot from the other program? If your data is not a stretched grid in x-y, then there are infinite ways to connect the points. The rows/cols needs to be connected with varying sides polygons, and there is no way to tell when the next row/col starts other than comparing the values. Show a sample of data that is not almost just zeros.

Comment: You must know *something* about your data. Where does it come from? Can it be saved in an other format? Can you preprocess the data file?

Comment: @hpekristiansen, yes, yes, and yes. However, I don’t follow why any of this is relevant to the question. The OP has all the information to address the question. Are you able to make a surf plot. I have attempted this an get an error, which I don’t understand. Data comes from simulations performed in Matlab. The visualisation tools demonstrate the data is a surface. However I want to make this plot in PGF, for which I have provided a relavent MWE.

Comment: As I write, I am not able to make the surface from the information given. I have provided the information needed to make it happen. Good luck.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Would a Csv file help? Also what sort of preprocessing is required?

Comment: No - The amount of data is sufficient, and the formatting is good. The problem is that the is no one way to interpret your data as a surface - it can be done in several ways. Triangulation, variable polygon, interpolation(also several ways). -a really simple way would be to repeat values until you have the mesh needed for PGFPlots. The more complex methods also require preprocessing, OR octave or gnuplot in combination with PGFPlots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149953/discussion-between-sid-and-hpekristiansen).